# Need Wrapper Solution References

Tags: java, android, jar, apk

I am looking for a wrapper solution examples or references.
Actually our next project is to build a market place where developer will upload their APK file.
The main challenge is during upload those APK file system will automatically wrap that uploaded APK file with some additional code.
When any user download any APK and install their device our additional code will execute to check the user status after that the user can access the main app.

Can anybody help me regarding this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to do is really challenging. We also have the similar requirements. In our product we need to launch some code within customers application. We didn't find any easy way to wrap customers application with our code. But we don't need to avoid application launch without our code. So in our case we create additional APK with our code and use [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) to launch customers APK from ours. Our customers know that if they need our functionality they need to start from our APK

As I understood it is not your case.

As I said we didn't find any easy way to wrap applications. There are two ways we found to do that. First is decompile and compile again with our code. But I don't know any reliable solution for that. Most of applications cannot be compiled again after decompilation. The second is byte code injection in onCreate() method of launcheable activity. It sounds more realistic for me. But still you have to know a lot about dex file format.

Good luck and share your solution if you find it after a while.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will share with you if I find any solution.

Comment: Is there any body to help me.

Comment: Hello anybody can help me?